# How to add element from sorted set in other sorted set sorting by score?

Tags: redis

I get one element from sorted set named as `Questions` with a score.
Also I have another sorted set `My`.

How I can add selected element from `Questions` to sorted set `My` ordering by score? Dont mix up with merge of sorted sets.

Comment: What's wrong with ZADD?